# Spring Boot Datasource in unit tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I have a simple Spring Boot web app, that reads from a database and return a JSON response. I have the following test configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=MyApplication.class, properties={"spring.config.name=myapp"})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ControllerTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    @MockBean
    private ProductRepository productRepo;
    @MockBean
    private MonitorRepository monitorRepo;
    
    @Before
    public void setupMock() {
        Mockito.when(productRepo.findProducts(anyString(), anyString()))
        .thenReturn(Arrays.asList(dummyProduct()));     
    }
    
    @Test
    public void expectBadRequestWhenNoParamters() throws Exception {    
        mvc.perform(get("/products"))
                .andExpect(status().is(400))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.advice.status", is("ERROR")));
    }

    //other tests
}
```

I have a `DataSource` bean that is configured in the main configuration of the application. When I run the tests Spring tries to load the context and fails, because the `DataSource` is taken from `JNDI`. In general I want to avoid creating a `DataSource` for this tests, because I have the repositories mocked.

Is it possible to skip the creation of `DataSource` when running the unit tests?

**Note:** In-memory database for testing is not an option, because my database creation script has a specific structure and cannot be easily executed from `classpath:schema.sql`

**Edit**

The datasource is defined in `MyApplication.class`

```
    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource(DatabaseProeprties databaseProps) throws NamingException {
       DataSource dataSource = null;
       JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
       setJndiEnvironment(databaseProps, jndi);
       try {
           dataSource = jndi.lookup(databaseProps.getName(), DataSource.class);
       } catch (NamingException e) {
           logger.error("Exception loading JNDI datasource", e);
           throw e;
       }
       return dataSource;
   }
```

Comment: Are your datasources configured via auto-configuration?

Comment: @wjans No, its' a bean in the main config. See my edit.

Comment: Can't you simply add the datasource as a `@MockBean DataSource dataSource` too then?  Think it has the advantage that your production code doing the JNDI lookup won't even be executed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are loading configuration class `MyApplication.class` datasource bean will be created, Try moving datasource in another bean which is not used in a test, make sure all classes loaded for tests are not dependant on datasource.
 Or 
In your tests create a config class marked with `@TestConfiguration` and include it in `SpringBootTest(classes=TestConfig.class)` mocking data source there like

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return Mockito.mock(DataSource.class);
}
```

But this may fail since method call to this mocked datasouce for connection will return null, In that case, you'll have to create an in-memory datasource and then mock jdbcTemplate and rest of dependencies.

Comment: Very convenient, thanks.  After adding a TestConfiguration in the log I get: `Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition`. I also created another TestConfiguration defining a real datasource, for the integration tests.

Comment: Doesn't this have a potential risk that the overriding will happen in a different order?  Think it's not a good idea to rely on this, think you should give the mocked bean a different name and annotate it with `@Primary` to be sure.  Still has the disadvantage that both beans will be created though.

Comment: I agree with @wjans

Comment: Hi, after try your solution, in my case I got the error of 
`BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]`

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

Try adding your datasource as a [`@MockBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) too:

```
@MockBean
private DataSource dataSource
```

That way Spring will do the replacing logic for you, having the advantage that your production code bean creation won't even be executed (no JNDI lookup).

Comment: This is my way of doing it too. You can add the MockBean to the `TestConfig.class` to minimize code duplication aswell.

Comment: great suggestion, worked with adding @MockBean(name = "your bean name") in test class