# jdbcTemplate is null, when using method with JUnit

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockmvc

I currently work on a Spring Project and I am now writing JUnit tests. My problem is, that the `jdbcTemplate` is null (tested with Debugger) in the method `getQuestions`, so it doesn't receive any data from the database. 
Everything else works just fine. So here's my code: 
I do this at the beginning of the controller class:

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

getQuestions:

```
@PostMapping("/question")
public List<String> getQuestions(@RequestBody int number){

    String query = "SELECT t.question " +
            "FROM question as t " +
            "ORDER BY RAND() " +
            "LIMIT " + number + ";";

    this.questionList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, String.class);
    this.index = number;

    return questionList;
}
```

I do this at the beginning of the Test class:

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
private MainController controller;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
            .build();
}
```

And the Test method:

```
@Test
public void getQuestions() throws Exception{
    int num = 4;

    mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/question")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                    .content(asJsonString(num))
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
    ).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}
```

Now I don't know how to get the `jdbcTemplate` not to be null. Also in the regular application the method works perfectly fine.

Comment: You test class should include configuration for test, using `@ContextConfiguration` for example

Comment: And what do I have to configure there?

Comment: Your configuration class(es)

Answer (score 0):

You need configure dataSource for test environment. If you use Spring Boot then try to create application.properties located in test/resources(Spring Boot will make everythin else)

for example, with h2 database

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

read part about dataSource properties in application.properties file https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source
and
[Spring Boot Datasource in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559185/spring-boot-datasource-in-unit-tests)

or if you don't use Spring Boot then you need to configure your env for test another way, it depends on conventions and rules in your project. I think, in any case, you need to find dataBase configuration for real set-up (it will be dataSource bean and all related stuff) and try to emulate it(Add TestConfiguration and substitute all needed beans there(or use @Mock annotation)